# Getting text from HTML (allElements)

Tags: html, powershell

I have a script that I use to login to a website, and it's working. For my next step, I need to get a link from the `$login.AllElements`.
The text I need is

```
administration/uploadprofileselector.aspx?l=English&uid=1234&oid=123456
```

How would I capture it from this?

I tried `$login.AllElements | ? {$_.innerHTML -like "File Upload Utility"}`, but it's not working.

```
PS> $login.AllElements

innerHTML : Main Menu
 ......more html stuff....
 item title="Transfer In And Out" url="reports/TransferInAndOut2.asp?l=English"
 item title="Seize Items" url="administration/SeizeReport.asp?l=English"
 item title="File Upload Utility" url="administration/uploadprofileselector.aspx?l=English&uid=1234&oid=123456" >
```

Inner HTML:

```html
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Main Menu</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language=javascript>
<!--
<item title="Seize Items" url="administration/SeizeReport.asp?l=English" ></item>
<item title="File Upload Utility" url="administration/uploadprofileselector.as px?l=English&amp;uid=1234&amp;oid=123456" ></item>
```

Comment: What's stopping you? What exactly do you need help with? What have you tried, and how does it fail?

Comment: The problem is that it can't find the text I'm looking for when I enter `$login.AllElements | ? {$_.innerHTML -like "File Upload Utility"}`  It's not showing anything.

Comment: `$login.AllElements |? {$_.title = 'File Upload Utility'}`?

Comment: @Mathias,Yes, I figured since it contains "File Upload Utility", I could capture that.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` would give you an element *containing* the actual element your after. If the element itself has an identifying attribute value (such as `title`), use that instead

Comment: this is the innerHTML                                                                                                      innerHTML : <HEAD><TITLE>Main Menu</TITLE>
            <SCRIPT language=javascript>
            <!--
            <item title="Seize Items" url="administration/SeizeReport.asp?l=English" 
            ></item>
            <item title="File Upload Utility" url="administration/uploadprofileselector.as
            px?l=English&amp;uid=1234&amp;oid=123456" ></item>

Comment: would the attribute be item title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're looking for is in an HTML comment, so you can't easily extract it with DOM methods. Try something like this:

```
$login.AllElements.InnerHtml | Where-Object {
    $_ -match 'url="(administration/uploadprofileselector.aspx\?.*?)"'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $matches[1]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.  Marked as answer!